# nginx server gzip is not working for json

Tags: http, nginx, proxy

i want to compress json response data . but it's not working.
cant't see the "Content-Encoding: gzip" in response headers and data size is not commpressed.
But html can be compressed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjdQA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNfoi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see from your small screenshot, but you need to make sure the `gzip_types` directive includes `application/json`.  For example:

```
gzip_types text/plain application/x-javascript application/json ...
```

This is probably declared in your `nginx.conf`.

If in doubt, a good default set up might be:

```
gzip_types
  application/atom+xml
  application/geo+json
  application/javascript
  application/x-javascript
  application/json
  application/ld+json
  application/manifest+json
  application/rdf+xml
  application/rss+xml
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  application/wasm
  application/x-web-app-manifest+json
  application/xhtml+xml
  application/xml
  font/eot
  font/otf
  font/ttf
  image/bmp
  image/svg+xml
  text/cache-manifest
  text/calendar
  text/css
  text/javascript
  text/markdown
  text/plain
  text/xml
  text/vcard
  text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
  text/vtt
  text/x-component
  text/x-cross-domain-policy;
```

Remember `text/html` is always compressed by default, so you don't need to include that.